# packaging a JAR file in root of WAR archive using maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to customise WAR archive generation with maven in a way that a certain client jar is at the root of a war file instead of default WEB-INF/lib directory

I used the `copy` goal of `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy this jar to location `${project.build.directory}${file.separator}${project.artifactId}-${project.version}` this copies it as expected i.e. target/mywar-1.0-SNAPSHOT folder

```
\-target
   |-mywar-1.0-SNAPSHOT
       |-WEB-INF
           |-lib
           |-classes
       |-something.jsp
       |-other-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

however, when the maven build generates a WAR archive this JAR is not included in the packaging in the root of WAR archive. How do I get the following WAR archive structure in place with maven?

```
\-mywar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.WAR
   |-WEB-INF
       |-lib
       |-classes
   |-something.jsp
   |-other-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

notice that this other jar should be at the same level as WEB-INF not inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I would think the war plugin takes its input from the src directory, not the target directory.  See the [war-mojo docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html).

What might help is [this howto on how to add additional resources into the war](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) file.

Comment: Thanks for the help @wemu! I had to hack my way through `maven-assembly-plugin` to re-bundle a WAR with JAR archive at root, the additional resources thing I didn't try because the JAR To be copied was essentially in the dependencies so I had to first use `maven-dependency-plugin` to move it to some directory then add through `resources`; using assembly seemed simpler to me.